# Load values from INI file to combo box

Tags: python, combobox, ini, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a `GUI` (created with *PyQt5 & Python3.4*). I have a pair of *combobox* : the first is brand of cars and the second one is models of the brand selected.

I have an `INI file` to save the last values entered in the `GUI`, so when I re open the `GUI`, the last values/parameters are automatically put.
This works for all my other parameters, except for the *combobox*.
I write the `currentIndex` in the `INI file`, when I close my `GUI` the correct index is written in the INI file, but when i open the `GUI` again, the index is changed to 0.

This is what my code looks like :

```
def comboSelect(self):

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('D:\File\save.ini')

    self.indexModel = ui.dmpModele.currentIndex()
    config.set('de_sec', 'dmp_modele', str(self.indexModel))

    with open('D:\File\save.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile) # write the index in the INI file

if __name__ == "__main__":

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('D:\File\save.ini')

    p.indexModel = config.get('de_sec', 'dmp_modele') # get the value of index from INI file
    ui.dumperModele.setCurrentIndex(int(p.indexModel)) # pass the index to combo box
```

What have I missed ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Some other part of your code must be resetting the index of the combo-box.

Comment: @ekhumoro I used to have a setCurrentIndex but I removed it. I'll look for something else that is causing the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro I can't seem to find anything that is resetting the index of the combobox. Do you have any ideas of what could be doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it. It was a stupid mistake.
In my

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

i was calling the functions before getting the values from the .ini file and so there were put to zero. That's it.

**UPDATE** : now the *index* is correct, but the name in the *combobox* is not. It doesn't change, even though I have set a `setCurrentIndex` with the correct *index*. How about that ?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't change? What is the output of `print(combo.currentText())` when placed immediately after the `setCurrentIndex` call?

Comment: @ekhumoro I know it doesn't change because i see it. I'm printing the index (and it's the correct one) but the name in the `combobox` is wrong, it doesn't match the correct index (it matches the index 0).

Comment: So, as I suggested before, it must be that some other part of your code is re-setting the current item.

Comment: @ekhumoro i've looked but i don't find anything. What else, other than `setCurrentIndex`can cause that, please ?

Comment: If the index is always reset to zero, a likely cause is that the items in the combo-box are being reset. But really, without seeing the actual code, it's impossible to give a useful answer. There can only be some many references to the combo-box in your code. Use your editor to find them all, then systematically comment each one out until the problem goes away.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes that must be it. Because the values of the combo box come from a database (csv file) and everytime the GUI is launched i go through the database, to see if any new values have been added. So it might come from this ?